# How to make a for loop in python for ttest_ind

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

When I try to make the for loop to get ttest results I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

But I have no idea what could be wrong with it. When I replace col with a specific column name it works and give me the same results over and over but it wont let me use col in brackets

```
df_columns = ['party','handicapped-infants','water-project',
                          'budget','physician-fee-freeze', 'el-salvador-aid',
                          'religious-groups','anti-satellite-ban',
                          'aid-to-contras','mx-missile','immigration',
                          'synfuels', 'education', 'right-to-sue','crime','duty-free',
                          'south-africa']

df = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/voting-records/house-votes-84.data", 
                 header=None, names=df_columns, na_values='?')

df = df.replace({'y':1, 'n':0})

rep = df[df['party']=='republican']
dem = df[df['party']=='democrat']

for col in df_columns:
  print(str(col))
  print(ttest_ind(rep[col], dem[col], nan_policy='omit'))
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, with a bit more playing around I realized what I had done wrong.

Here was my quick fix.

```
for col in df_columns:
  if col == 'party':
    print("Skipped")
  else:
    print(str(col))
    print(ttest_ind(rep[col], dem[col], nan_policy='omit'))
```

Comment: still opened to suggestions. I'm sure there is a better way to do this without using an if than statement but it works for now

Comment: If the error is being raised by the value stored in `col` I would suggest using a `try except` clause.